# Mandarin Chinese Walla

Tags: sound-design, sound, dialogue, walla

Does anyone have any Mandarin walla they'd be willing to share or suggestions on where to find it? I'd be into doing a trade for some of my own field recordings. Preferably looking for something very quiet or with whispers

Comment: Are you trying to find walla. crowd, or background sounds? Walla you won't be able to tell what they are saying nor the language.

Comment: I've been to China and have made field recordings in several places/situations. What is the context/place that you need the walla/sound for? A temple or a busy shopping centre? Help us help you :)